# Is it possible to call ImageButtonClick event within other checkbox event in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a situation which i am explaining below:

I am using this image button click event in my application

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click (object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

and i need to call this event inside checkbox event below:

```
 protected void Matt_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Matt.Checked==true) && (Rematt1.Checked == false) && (Rematt2.Checked == false) && (Rematt3.Checked == false))
        {
            txtTumblingRefno_TextChanged(sender,e);
            btnUpdate_Click(sender,e);
        }
       else
        {
        }
  }
```

Here I'm calling `textchanged` event within this checkbox event but i couldn't call imagebuttonclick event within the checkbox event. It shows that there are some invalid arguments.

Please help me regarding this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ImageClickEventArgs.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty(v=vs.110).aspx), Pass this value to event handlers that are associated with events that do not have data.

```
protected void Matt_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Matt.Checked==true) && (Rematt1.Checked == false) && (Rematt2.Checked == false) && (Rematt3.Checked == false))
        {
            txtTumblingRefno_TextChanged(sender,e);
            btnUpdate_Click(sender,ImageClickEventArgs.Empty);
        }
       else
        {
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageButton click hanlder has different event args (which is ImageClickEventArgs) than standard EventArgs. Thats why you are getting compiler error. As you aren't using the args any way, you can simply send null as args (see below):

```
protected void Matt_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Matt.Checked==true) && (Rematt1.Checked == false) && (Rematt2.Checked == false) && (Rematt3.Checked == false))
    {
        txtTumblingRefno_TextChanged(sender,e);
        btnUpdate_Click(sender, null);
    }
   else
    {
    }
}
```

You could have also written whatever you need in a separate method which can be called anywhere.